# How do I test whether an HttpException is a "The client disconnected." error?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, httpexception

I would like to test whether an HttpException is a disconnected error.

A naive implementation would check the message:

```
bool IsClientDisconnectedError(HttpException exception)
{
   return exception.Message == "The client disconnected.";
}
```

How can I check for a client disconnected error without depending on the exception message?

Comment: If (exception.ErrorCode == Whatever) ?

Comment: The ErrorCode looks ambiguous: 0x8004005 (E_FAIL).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just check the error code of the exception, documentation on `HttpException` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx), and on `ErrorCode` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception.errorcode(v=vs.110).aspx), with an explanation on what the arguments returned by `ErrorCode` mean [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa378137.aspx).

---

For posterity, if you don't want to read the comments below this answer, it's also possible to try logging the `Source` and `HttpCode` to gather more information and find a unique code for a particular exception.

Comment: I think that the ErrorCode is E_FAIL "Unspecified failure". How can I tell that this code uniquely corresponds to "The client disconnected."?

Comment: Could you try printing `exception.Source` to the console? I'm kind of curious if something else might be going on. It should display the name of the application or the object that causes the error.

Comment: I'll try logging the Source, ErrorCode and HttpCode to see if any of these give a specific way to test for the "client disconnected" condition.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how it goes!